# How to show value of input in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, validation, input

I have this input field in a form:

```
<form method="post" class="tester" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
    <input type="number" name="test">
    </form>
```

Whenever I try to get the input / value of the input data, filled in by my users, I can not show it (it just does not echo it). This is the code I use to echo it:

```
<?php 
$well = $_POST['test'];
echo $well;
?>
```

I tried using `GET` as well, but nothing works.

**var_dump** gives me:

```
array(0) { }
```

Can you help?

Comment: Is that code in the `action` script of the form?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: No, it's outside of the form... I want to show the value outside of the form after submit.

Comment: I mean the form should have `action="scriptname.php"` in it. Is this the code of that script?

Comment: `<form method="post" action="scriptname.php">`

Comment: Ah, the form is: <form method="post" class="tester" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">

Comment: If you have `action="#"` submitting the form doesn't do anything.

Comment: That would be used if you're processing the form in JavaScript, maybe using AJAX.

Comment: var_dump gives me: array(0) { }

Comment: How are you sending the form to PHP?

Comment: actually open the devtools while you send the request, and verify the data is sent to begin with. you can right click the request and copy it as well, if you want to paste it here.

Comment: I think you're running that code when the page is first opened, not when the form is submitted. It should be inside `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Answer (score 0):

Your form do not seem to have any issue even after using **hash#** it still process the form. Also your PHP code it's fine.

index.php

```
<form method="post" class="tester" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
    <input type="number" name="test">
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $well = $_POST['test'];
    echo $well;
    //print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me.